# EMF version compatible to Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse

I want to install EMF,GEF,WTP,MDT in Eclipse 4.4 (Luna). How I can get the information for  compatible versions?

Comment: Just go to "Install software" and pick the version it offers you,

Answer (score 0):

Use the Luna plugin repository, where all plugins are at compatible versions.

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Here is the url. It has the information all supported packages' version.
https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/luna